# gcloud execute commands on remote instance not working as expected

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, centos, gcloud

I'm new with gcp and gcloud commands.
I'm trying to run the following -

```
[root@localhost ~]# gcloud compute ssh test --zone=us-central1-a --command=DISK_DEV=`lsblk | grep -i 10g | awk '{print $1}'` ; echo $DISK_DEV

[root@localhost ~]# gcloud compute ssh test --zone=us-central1-a --command="DISK_DEV=`lsblk | grep -i 10g | awk '{print $1}'` ; echo $DISK_DEV"
```

and it doesn't return the expected output (as it returns null instead of the relevant device).

If I run it on the remote instance, the same command returns the expected output (the device) -

```
[root@test ~]# DISK_DEV=`lsblk | grep -i 10g | awk '{print $1}'` ; echo $DISK_DEV
sdb
```

Please advice,
Thank you.

Comment: Each `gcloud` command creates a different SSH session. Environment variables created in one session are not shared with other/future sessions. Either create a script as DazWilkin suggests or save the variable to a file and read back in the next session.

Answer (score 3):

`gcloud` runs on your local host and invokes the command on the remote host.

You're trying to set an environment variable (`DISK_DEV`) on your local host to reflect the value on the remote host. This doesn't work.

Your command is syntactically incorrect too; you can't `--command=[VAR]="..."`.

See: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh#--command

The only way to get this to work is to run the command `lsblk | grep -i 10g | awk '{print $1}'` and capture the output of the `gcloud` command and then parse that:

```sh
RESULT="$(gcloud ... --command='lsblk ...')"
```

<strike>I don't have an easy way to test the above but `RESULT` may include additional data from the remote shell that needs to be pruned.</strike>

#### Update

This works:

```sh
COMMAND="lsblk | grep -i 10g"

RESULT=$(\
  gcloud compute ssh ${INSTANCE} \
  --zone=${ZONE} \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --command="${COMMAND}")

DISK_DEV=$(echo ${RESULT} | awk '{print $1}')
echo ${DISK_DEV}
sda
```

Comment: Thank you very much!